# Unable to update or install *anything* because of curl conflict

Tags: kubuntu, curl

```
KDE Plasma Version: 5.24.7
KDE Frameworks Version: 5.92.0
Qt Version: 5.15.3
Kernel Version: 5.15.0-60-generic (64-bit)
```

I can't upgrade from Discover or from the terminal. I get the following error(s):

```
 libcurl4-openssl-dev : Depends: libcurl4 (= 7.81.0-1ubuntu1.7) but 7.81.0-1ubuntu1.8 is to be installed
                        Breaks: libcurl4-openssl-dev:i386 (!= 7.81.0-1ubuntu1.7) but 7.81.0-1ubuntu1.8 is to be installed
 libcurl4-openssl-dev:i386 : Breaks: libcurl4-openssl-dev (!= 7.81.0-1ubuntu1.8) but 7.81.0-1ubuntu1.7 is to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

I've been on the googles for an hour so far and haven't found anything that helps with the issue. How do I fix this so I can update my PC?

Edit: apt policy libcurl4 libcurl4-openssl-dev libcurl4-openssl-dev:i386 outputs

```
  Installed: 7.81.0-1ubuntu1.8
  Candidate: 7.81.0-1ubuntu1.8
  Version table:
 *** 7.81.0-1ubuntu1.8 500
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     7.81.0-1 500
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/main amd64 Packages
libcurl4-openssl-dev:
  Installed: 7.81.0-1ubuntu1.7
  Candidate: 7.81.0-1ubuntu1.8
  Version table:
     7.81.0-1ubuntu1.8 500
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security/main amd64 Packages
 *** 7.81.0-1ubuntu1.7 100
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     7.81.0-1 500
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/main amd64 Packages
libcurl4-openssl-dev:i386:
  Installed: 7.81.0-1ubuntu1.8
  Candidate: 7.81.0-1ubuntu1.8
  Version table:
 *** 7.81.0-1ubuntu1.8 500
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/main i386 Packages
        500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security/main i386 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     7.81.0-1 500
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/main i386 Packages
```

`sudo apt --fix-broken install` just returns

```
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/libcurl4-openssl-dev_7.81.0-1ubuntu1.8_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite shared '/usr/bin/curl-config', which is different from other instances of package libcurl4-openssl-dev:amd64
dpkg-deb: error: paste subprocess was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/libcurl4-openssl-dev_7.81.0-1ubuntu1.8_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Comment: `sudo apt -f install --reinstall libcurl4-openssl-dev=7.81.0-1ubuntu1.8` please.

Comment: @nobody ended up with the same output as just `sudo apt -f install`

Comment: Okay first aid `sudo mv /usr/bin/curl-config $HOME` and try again please.

Comment: @nobody that fixed it! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

It look like a conflict, do the following, open a terminal then do `sudo apt --fix-broken install` , if this does not fix try `sudo apt-get install libcurl4=7.81.0-1ubuntu1.7 libcurl4-openssl-dev=7.81.0-1ubuntu1.7 libcurl4-openssl-dev:i386=7.81.0-1ubuntu1.7` then do the classic `sudo apt update` then `sudo apt upgrade`